# How to find the index of a div which having the property display:block in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I need  to find the index of a div which having the property display:block,in jQuery.

html structure is like :

```
<div id="bb-bookblock" class="bb-bookblock bb-vertical" >     

    <div class="bb-item" style="display: none;"> </div>
    <div class="bb-item" style="display: none;"> </div>
    <div class="bb-item" style="display: none;"> </div>
    <div class="bb-item" style="display: block;"> </div>
    <div class="bb-item" style="display: none;"> </div>
    <div class="bb-item" style="display: none;"> </div>
</div>
```

where the child div are generated dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[attribute  contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)** or **[`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)** pseudo-class selector to get the element and then get it's index using **[`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/)** method.

```js
console.log(
  $('.bb-item[style*="display: block"]').index(),
  $('.bb-item:visible').index()
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bb-bookblock" class="bb-bookblock bb-vertical">
  <div class="bb-item" style="display: none;"></div>
  <div class="bb-item" style="display: none;"></div>
  <div class="bb-item" style="display: none;"></div>
  <div class="bb-item" style="display: block;"></div>
  <div class="bb-item" style="display: none;"></div>
  <div class="bb-item" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I used the same code but always displaying index as -1

Comment: @Pravav : I put the code out of document.ready function then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Please refer below code**

```
$("#bb-bookblock").find("div[style='display: block;']").index();
```